# Firebase Snapshot.data Double Map to use

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a map in Firebase and get the slider values ​​from there. But it gives an error. "type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<Double, Double>' in type cast
"

[image]

```
Expanded(
  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("deger").doc("1")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
       final  Map<Double, Double> map = snapshot.data!["item"] as  Map<Double, Double>;
          return VerticalSlider(
            min: parameters.minDecibels,
            max: parameters.maxDecibels,
            value: map as double,
            onChanged: band.setGain,
          );

      }),
),
```

I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: change your map to Map<String, dynamic> as the key value is a String : "item1"

Comment: "items" a number. I need to get number double for slider. I don't need to get string.

Comment: I think you're not familiar with Maps. Check frank's comment below for better explanation.

Comment: Yes, I'm not familiar with it at all. I'm trying to use it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the `items` are **not** a number. They're strings like `"item1"`, `"item2"`, etc.

If you want to interpret just the number part of those (i.e. `1`, `2`, etc), you will have to parse the key in your code.

Something like:

```
snapshot.data!["item"].map((key, value) => MapEntry(int.parse(key.substring(4)), value));
```

So the above first removes the `"item"` prefix from the string, and then converts the remained to a number.

A complete example I [tested in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=671802864024e8c2962bb7a3ec21b98d):

```
const item = {
  "item1": 1.5,
  "item2": 1.5,
  "item3": 1.5,
};

void main() {
  final updated = item.map((key, value) => MapEntry(int.parse(key.substring(4)), value));
  print(updated);
  final typed = updated as Map<double,double>;
  print(typed);
}
```

Comment: error: type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<Double, Double>'. I changed the items to numbers in firebase, like 1,2, but it still didn't work.

Comment: First off: does the explanation of why your initial approach doesn't work that I gave at the top of my answer make sense? If so, does it also make sense how the approach I showed would address that problem? And third: did you try running the code snippet I gave at the bottom standalone, and did that indeed convert the string keys to the numeric value you want?

Comment: My guess is that this is because I used `int.parse` and you use `Map<double,double>`. You can use `double.parse` or use `Map<int, double>`.

Comment: Of course your answer makes sense. I didn't run it alone because it already fixed the string error. I used it as I shared below. But my code block wants it as double, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I used double parse and it still gives the same error. type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Comment: final double map = snapshot.data!["item"].map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key.substring(4)), value)); This doesn't happen either.